# Stacking standard output of `su`

Tags: php, bash, unix

I've got some code that I wrote that uses a combination of bash and PHP command line scripting. The script is ran as root and then uses `su` to become various uses. I start a session like this:

```
$result = `su SomeUser ./dothis.php`
```

Here `./dothis.php` is a script that may generate some output being stored in `$result`, but the problem is that there is usually output that doesn't get caught and makes it hard for me to read my script output.

How can I make sure that the output is being captured within this `su` stacking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `2>&1` to redirect stderr to stdout. Backticks only capture output to stdout and will miss output to stderr.

```
$result = `su SomeUser ./dothis.php 2>&1`
```